# Understanding this program that makes a calendar?

Tags: javascript, parsing, calendar

I am studying a program that makes a calendar. When logging numbers in a YYYY/MM/DD format this should happen:

```
console.log(talkingCalendar("2004/11/01"));    =>  November 1st, 2004
console.log(talkingCalendar("2007/11/11"));    =>  November 11th, 2011
console.log(talkingCalendar("1987/08/24"));    =>  August 24th, 1987
```

This is what I'm studying:

```
function tensFn(day) {
  var output = 0;
  if (day.length > 1) {
    output = day[0];
  }

    return output;
  }

function getOrdinal(day) {
  var ones = day.toString().split('').pop();
   ones = parseInt(ones);
   var tens = parseInt(tensFn(day), 10);
   var ordinate = '';
   if (tens == 0  || tens == 2) {
     switch (ones) {
     case 1:
       ordinate = 'st';
       break;
     case 2:
       ordinate = 'nd';
       break;
     case 3:
       ordinate = 'rd';
       break;
     case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
      ordinate = 'th';
      break;
  }

  }


  if (tens == 1) {
    switch (ones) {
    case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
     ordinate = 'th';
  }

  }

  return ordinate;
}
```

This is the part that I don't fully grasp:

```
function getOrdinal(day) {
  var ones = day.toString().split('').pop();
   ones = parseInt(ones);
   var tens = parseInt(tensFn(day), 10);
   var ordinate = '';
```

What is the author doing with var ones, why convert it to a string, split then pop before parsing?

Comment: As you note, it is ugly, what is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Search MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript for split and pop. Or use console.log() to see what it does. `console.log(day, day.toString(), day.toString().split(''), day.toString().split('').pop())`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see it is used to separate the days. Example number 27 is divided into 20 and 7.

```
 function getOrdinal(day) {                         Example day = 27
    var ones = day.toString().split('').pop();      convert 27 to '27', split on chars ['2','7'] and pop '7'
    ones = parseInt(ones);                          convert to integer the result from above 7 
    var tens = parseInt(tensFn(day), 10);           get the first number when days length is greater than 1. In this case returns 2 
}
```

---

In my opinion a better approach to do that would be:

```
function getOrdinal(day){           Example day = 27
    var ones = day % 10             get 27 mod 10 = 7
    var tens = day / 10 |0          get difference of days / ten, then floor it. Result is 2
    var ordinate = '';
    ...
```

```js
function getOrdinal(day){      
 var ones = day % 10        
 var tens = day / 10 |0 
 return [ones, tens]
}

console.log(getOrdinal(27))
```